# CSS - Header background image not showing after file rename and relocation

Tags: html, css

I started these files in a different location and under different filenames. I decided I liked what I had, so I changed the filenames to something more permanent for the project and moved them to another file folder. Since that time, my header image will not show.

All markup and css code reflects the new file names and locations and everything else in the page layout renders just like it did before. Only the header image is missing.

Does anyone see something in the code that I've overlooked?

**HTML**

```
<div id="headerbox">
        <header>
            <h1>Southern Draw Archery of Coweta</h1>
        </header>
       </div>`
```

**CSS**

```
#headerbox {background-image: url("images/archery.jpg");
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        left: 200px;
        right: 200px;
        top: 0px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;}

#headerbox header {position: absolute;
               bottom: 0;
               left: 0;
               width: 100%;
               padding: 20px 10px;}

#headerbox header h1 {margin: 0px;
                  color: white;
                  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
                  position: relative;}
```

-------A quick edit for the comments below-------

The css and image are both in their own separate folders, while the HTML files are in the main (root) project folder. So the file structure is like so:

main project folder
/                 \
css folder        images folder
/                   \
css file             image files

I've tried moving the image source to the HTML markup and the image did show back up, but the rest of the css settings wouldn't apply to it. Before I moved everything, all the code rendered like it was supposed to, as written below.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of or write down your directory tree?

Comment: i test your code and all run on my side. How do you include your file ? have you got some error in the browser console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your CSS file in a separate folder (i.e. not on the same level as your HTML file)?

Then `{background-image: url("images/archery.jpg")` should  be changed to `{background-image: url("../images/archery.jpg")` or similar

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks Johannes. I figured it was something simple I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that

> url("images/archery.jpg");

Is the correct file path to your image?

I changed the image src to something else and I saw the background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error on css part. First of all check your image name and extension. May be your image file is in png format. Even if the image is not showing then you might have placed your css file in separate folder. So change your css to

```
#headerbox {background-image: url("../images/archery.jpg");
```